# How to have two galleries side by side?

Tags: gallery

I have two galleries on one page, but one is on top of the other. How can I make them appear side by side? I need them to stay as two different galleries, so combining them isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign each of those 2 galleries a div and in the css add:-

```
      .gallery-1 {
                  width: 48%;
                  float: left;
                 }
      .gallery-2 {
                  width: 48%;
                  float: left;
                  position:relative;
                 }
```